# Nested Lists in Python - Shifting entries alongside dimensions efficiently

Tags: python

Good evening,

I am trying to generalize the histogram filter localization to discrete environments of arbitrary dimensionality. Even though at this point working with numpy would probably be the best choice, I would like to stick to certain constraints of an assignment which itself got me started with this whole 2D- to higher-dimensional-capability thing.

For a start, I chose a cubic environment (each segment labelled from 1 to 27):

```
debug = [[['1', '2', '3'],
          ['4', '5', '6'],
          ['7', '8', '9']],
         [['10', '11', '12'],
          ['13', '14', '15'],
          ['16', '17', '18']],
         [['19', '20', '21'],
          ['22', '23', '24'],
          ['25', '26', '27']]]
```

During histogram localization a robot first moves and subsequently measures an input which helps gathering information about where the robot itself is residing. In my limited discrete 3D-cube-environment, my robot can fly up/down, move left/right and go forward/backward. Each time I need to perform an update alongside the robots movement direction (i.e. alter probability of residing in a certain segment).

Moving Forward/Backward would mean altering the rows {1,10,19},{2,11,20},{3,12,21},... and so on, while going left/right would mean altering the rows {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},... Ultimately, going up and down would mean altering {1,4,7},...
So this is where I am, with relatively limited basic python knowledge, I found myself in struggle with generalizing from 2- to 3D - however would even like it to work for higher dimensional environments. Any ideas on what to do next? Are there fancy ways to transform given lists of lists such that updates as described previously would become a straightforward task (if they are not already)?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a list of lists, using a `numpy.ndarray` will make things much easier for the fancy indexing/slicing/transformations you need.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array(range(1, 28)).reshape((3, 3, 3))
>>> x
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]],

       [[19, 20, 21],
        [22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27]]])
>>> x[:,0,0]
array([ 1, 10, 19])
>>> x[0,:,0]
array([1, 4, 7])
>>> x[0,0,:]
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: that's what I would usually do. started out without numpy due to an assignmnt's constraint and - for a change - just wanted to go on without it.
Thanks for your answer nonetheless! (would upvote if I could)

Comment: OK, but what benefits do you hope to get from _not_ using numpy?

Comment: None to be honest, I'd rather expect drawbacks. Having invested some hours today trying to figure out something "smart", just got my ambition running ;)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in how I ended up solving it without numpy and for arrays of arbitrary dimension, here's the code:

```
def move(array, U):
'''
@attention: Only works on flattened arrays
'''
q = [0] * len(array)

if (sum(U) != 1):
    return array

for i in range(len(U)):

    if (U[i] != 0):
        dim = i
        step = U[i]

if (dim == len(__envdim) - 1):
    stepsize = 1
    skipsize = __envdim[dim]

else:
    stepsize = reduce(lambda x,y: x * y, __envdim[(dim + 1):])
    skipsize = 1

for i in range(__getmoveturns(dim)):

    for j in range(__envdim[dim]):
        startProb = array[(j*stepsize + i*skipsize)]
        q[((j+step)*stepsize%(stepsize * __envdim[dim]) + i*skipsize)] += startProb * p_move
        q[(j*stepsize + i*skipsize)] += startProb * (1 - p_move)
        # print array[(j*stepsize + i*skipsize)], array[((j+1)*stepsize%(stepsize * __envdim[dim]) + i*skipsize)],

return q
```

It's rather quick and dirty and untested, however. __envdim is a list which holds the dimensions of the environment. Say, we have a 3x3x3 cube, that would be [3,3,3].
__getmoveturns returns the product of the lengths of all dimensions excluding the one in which my move is directed.